# Can't access id with getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string variable which contains an html value.

```
sAttachment = "<HTML><BODY><TABLE><TR id='tr1'><td>...</td></TR><TR id='tr2'><td>..</td></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
```

What I want to do is delete tr1 and all elements under it but I can't access it using getelementbyid.

```
var htmldoc = document.createElement('div');
htmldoc.innerHTML = sAttachment;
```

`htmldoc.getElementById('tr1')` --> object doesn't support this property or method.

Why can't I do this? or is there any other way so that I can remove tr1 without creating another element?

Using javascript. thanks in advance

Comment: You are appending a `<html>` inside a `<div>`..?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just a string then you can do the below solution..

```
sAttachment = "<HTML><BODY><TABLE><TR id='tr1'><td>...</td></TR><TR id='tr2'><td>..</td></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>"

//convert string to JQuery element
var str = $(sAttachment);
//remove tr1 element
str.find('[id="tr1"]').remove()
//get back new string
var newStr = str.html();
```

Comment: this will also remove the td and all other elements under it?

Comment: but you said in your question `What I want to do is delete tr1 and all elements under it but I can't access it using getelementbyid.` So what is your expected result?

Comment: I think your expected result should be `<HTML><BODY><TABLE><TR id='tr2'><td>..</td></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>`. correct?

Answer (score 4):

Because the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element) object does not have a method called [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById), it is present in the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document) object.

Instead for [modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector#Browser_compatibility) try to use the [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector) method like

```
htmldoc.querySelector('#tr1')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/psYc7/)

Comment: @AedzMigraso I think it is supported in IE8 - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector#Browser_compatibility

Comment: another option is to use jQuery like `$(htmldoc).find('#tr1')` - it will return a jQuery object not a dom reference. to get dom element reference `$(htmldoc).find('#tr1')[0]`

Comment: I don't think that's true.. I'm getting Object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: @AedzMigraso then try the jQuery solution - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/psYc7/2/

Answer (score 1):

using `Jquery.`

```
var $elem = $('#tr1');
```

It selects the `TR` what has the `id` of `tr1`